# Make a link activate on doubleclick only

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a very simple web-based file browser for my website.

I've styled my links to look like files and I want to be able to single-click to select them so I can do things like rename etc, and I want to be able to double-click to actually activate the link and download the file.

I've come up with the following, but it looks ugly. Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function nullClick()
{
    //do select stuff
    return false;
}

function dolink(link)
{
    window.location(link.href);
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="http://pathtofile" onclick="return nullClick();" ondblclick="dolink(this);">Clicky</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like a reasonable approach... What are you unhappy about?

Comment: it was the `dolink(this)` and `window.location = ...` that felt clumsy when the link works so nicely in its unmolested form. I may just rework it to 'enhance progressively', the system already displays a new page with rename/delete etc options for each file, I just wanted to jazz it up a bit.

Comment: The only feedback I'd offer is that folks have come to expect how links work...  As long as you are styling it appropriately so as not so confuse people, I think this is a fine approach.  If you have a framework to help you out, it can help take some of the "clutter" out of your HTML.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the `dblclick` event, you'll be breaking your links completely in the older browsers that don't support it (it was originally an IE-only extension).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid doing this since it goes against how users expected web sited to function, but if you must, the way you do it is the only way I know of.

Also, you should know that the site will fall back to single-clickable links if javascript is disabled or unavailable.

Comment: I agree, the site it really only for my own use, and the `nullClick` method would actually restyle the link to look 'selected'.

Comment: He needs more than to just ignore the onclick, so the nullClick() function does make sense in the example.  Read the question again - "I want to be able to single-click to select them so I can do things like rename etc"

Comment: I see, then ignore my previous comment about removing the function. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'm intending to progressively enhance the filebrowser anyway, so it already behaves sensibly on single-click (loads a new page with fileinfo and functions), just wanted to check if there was a better way of doing it really.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="http://pathtofile" onclick="return false" ondblclick="window.location = 'some where'">Clicky</a>
```

I think it would be more elegant solution with one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any JavaScript framework, that is probably as good as it gets. You could get rid of your functions thou;

```
<a href="..." onclick="return false;" ondblclick="location.href='...';">Foobar</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to a little [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/dblclick):

```
$("#yourLinkId").dblclick(function () { 
      window.location($(this).attr("href")); 
    });
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but after using it for five minutes, I was sold :)

Comment: It's also cheating if you require doubleclicks in links.

Comment: I enjoy the challenge and I learn a lot more rolling my own where I can! @BalusC I take the point, it was more of a shortcut so I can do things to the files and still download them without a page load.

Comment: You can do the same in almost as little code using plain JavaScript, assigning to the `ondblclick` property.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [jQuery](http://jquery.com)?

HTML example:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('link1')" class="dblclick">link1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:alert('link2')" class="dblclick">link2</a><br>
<a href="javascript:alert('link3')" class="dblclick">link3</a><br>
```

jQuery example:

```
$('a.dblclick')
    .bind('click', function() { return false; })
    .bind('dblclick', function() { window.location = this.href; });
```

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(init);
            function init() {
                $('a.dblclick')
                    .bind('click', function() { return false; })
                    .bind('dblclick', function() { window.location = this.href; });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:alert('link1')" class="dblclick">link1</a><br>
        <a href="javascript:alert('link2')" class="dblclick">link2</a><br>
        <a href="javascript:alert('link3')" class="dblclick">link3</a><br>
    </body>
</html>
```